# systemctl debian 8 jessie: Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1

Tags: debian, systemd, debian-jessie, dbus, systemctl

Unfortunately, in my Debian 8 jessie systemctl does not work at all.

Every `systemctl` command results in:

`Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1`

> systecmtl status udev
>
> > Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1

How can I fix it?

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: What happens if you run `systemctl status` as root?

Comment: Is dbus running? Are there related entries in /var/log/syslog or the output of `journalctl` ? Is there anything that changed in the system before this error started happening?

Comment: [This one](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=763299) maybe?  That is, you prevented `systemd` from replacing `sysvinit` when upgrading from Wheezy, and so you have the latter running as the init superserver, and hence `systemctl` has no one to talk to. Does `service udev status` work?

Comment: In general, I recommend to just [google for the exact error message](https://www.google.com/search?q="Failed+to+get+D-Bus+connection:+Unknown+error+-1") because in cases like this, chances are high you're not the first one with such problem. And in this case, you really are not ;-)

Comment: @kostix:
service udev status
[ ok ] udevd is running

Comment: For me `apt-get install --reinstall systemd-sysv` followed by rebooting fixed it. This solution is specific to Debian Jessie and the way it handles SysVInit and systemd beside each other.